# How ROS Packages work with each other?

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update2:

As the source code is configured in a catkin workspace, does every package needs a catkin work space or I can put all what I need and what I am developing in one workspace?

Thanks for the answer from @jarvisschultz

---

Update:

If I want to make modification to some packages, should it be installed by source or sudo install? Any difference?

Thanks for the answer from @jarvisschultz

---

How ros packages work with each other?

There are packages built from source or built from binary packages, but how do they work?

Any explanations or examples are welcomed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231365/how-ros-packages-work-with-each-other?/) by [rosder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26488/rosder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-04-11**:
If you would like to modify the source code for packages you should definitely be installing the packages from source. One reason would be that many apt-get packages don't include the source code (e.g. C++ nodes will only include the compiled binary not the code).

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-04-11**:
As another rule of thumb, you generally want to avoid editing code, configurations, scripts, etc. that are placed in areas of your filesystem requiring "root access". Let's say you edit a Python script in /opt/ros/indigo/ . Then the next update to the containing package will overwrite your changes.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-04-11**:
The "root access" rule, of course, doesn't always apply. Sometimes you have to edit these things, but try to avoid it unless absolutely necessary.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-04-13**:
You can put many packages into a single workspace. You may also want to investigate the concept of workspace chaining AKA workspace overlaying. http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you read the [ROS Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/Packages) page describing the concept of packages. It provides detailed explanations of what a package is, what may be included in a package, how packages define dependencies on other packages, how command line tools and ROS introspection tools operate within the package construct, and more. The distinction of a "binary" package (a package installed with `apt-get`... a debian package) and a source package (a package that is most likely in a catkin workspace that was compiled on your machine with `catkin_make`) has very little to do with what a package itself is. If you find yourself confused by the descriptions on the linked page, please edit your original question to provide more detailed questions.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2